# Changes not effect in the latest jar using maven

Tags: java, maven

I need to do some enhanements in struts2-jquery grid plugin.  I downloaded the source from https://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk.  I changed the logic in this source.  When I execute my POM.xml file using **mvn package**.  I received the exception

```
 "The project com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-grid-plugin:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT 
    have 1 error

        Non-resolvable parent POM:could not find artifact com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-
jquery:pom:3.5.0-snapshot and 'Parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @line 5,c
olumn 13  "
```

My pom.xml file is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>struts2-jaquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
    <name>Struts 2 jQuery Grid Plugin</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</developerConnection>
        <url>http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/</url>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tobago</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.39</version>
                <configuration>
                    <A>
                        uri=/struts-jquery-grid-tags,
                        tlibVersion=${tlib.version},
                        jspVersion=2.0,
                        shortName=sjg,
                        displayName="Struts2 jQuery Grid Tags",
                        outFile=${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/struts-jquery-grid-tags.tld,
                        description="Struts2 tags based on jQuery and jqGrid.",
                        outTemplatesDir=${basedir}/src/site/docs
                    </A>
                    <resourceTargetPath>target</resourceTargetPath>
                    <fork>false</fork>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <nocompile>true</nocompile>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <factory>
                        org.apache.struts.annotations.taglib.apt.TLDAnnotationProcessorFactory
                    </factory>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->

        <!-- struts-annotations must be in compile scope for maven-apt-plugin to
             function correctly. Marking it optional to exclude it from transitive dependency resolution -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

As per my understanding, the parent tag looks at another pom.xml file.  I tried to add a relative path in parent tag, but it's not working.  I didn't see the parent pom.xml in https://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk.

I removed the parent tag and added it into groupid , artifactId & version gave as 3.5.0-SNAPSHOT then its also failed.  Again i changed 3.4.0 instead of 3.5.0-SNAPSHOT then its build .jar file.  But its not effected my changes.

So how to run the pom file with latest changes of the code.Is there any alternative to create .jar file instead of run the pom.xml file.

Comment: The parent pom is there in the repository: http://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the build is failing is because there are dependencies (namely the parent pom and the struts2-jquery-plugin) that can't be found in the local repository, or in the current *reactor build*. The term reactor build refers to the project from which you run `mvn` and all child projects, referenced by `<module>` elements in the pom.

In your case, you either need to:

- `mvn install` the parent pom and struts2-jquery-plugin into your local repository, and try what you're doing again;
- change up a directory (i.e. to the trunk directory), and build the grid plugin as part of a reactor build that includes the parent pom and struts2-jquery-plugin.

**First approach**: If you go to the top-level of your checkout, i.e. `trunk`, and then run:

```
mvn -pl .,struts2-jquery-plugin install
```

It will install the snapshot versions of the parent pom and struts2-jquery-plugin into your local repository. You should then be able to run `mvn package` in the grid plugin directory.

**Second approach**: From `trunk`, you could run:

```
mvn -am -pl struts2-jquery-grid-plugin package
```

This will build the grid plugin together with any dependencies found in the reactor build, i.e. the parent pom, and the struts2-jquery-plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

As per error it trying download `com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-grid-plugin:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT` since there is no version like this in maven repository.

replace your pom with below dependency, it will build fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```